# What is simplest pagination code for php & mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have read many of code on stacoverflow for pagination with php & mysql but i just want simplest one. like no next/prev button only page numbers like 1 2 3 4 ...n. Please tell the simplest code , im strucked in this since 2 days
ive tried all codes which confuse me all time .
Every help would be appreciated .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 2 SQLs to make it working:

1 - get total count:

```
SELECT count(*) FROM ...
```

used for pagination, eg how many pages, page 1,2,3...

2 - get the records for a page:

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT 20,10
```

10 means pagesize 10 records per page, 20 means from 20th records which means page #3

Answer (score 0):

The basic logic behind the pagination is

take total number of rows from the table

```
$total_rows = SELECT count(*) FROM ...
```

then number of rows you need to show in a page

```
$perpage = "10";
```

total pagination link

```
$pages = ceil($total_rows/$perpage);
```

you can create link like this

```
for($i=1;$i<=$pages;$i++)
{
   $limit = $i*$perpage;
   echo "<a href='path/to/file/?limit='$limit">.$i."</a>";
 }

  if($_GET['limit']&&is_numeric($_GET['limit']))
   {
       $limitDb = $_GET['limit'];
    }
   else
  {
     $limitDb=10;
  }
```

then write query to get the data by limit

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT $limitDb,$perpage
```